# Conventions naming sed script?

Tags: linux, sed, naming-conventions

I know it doesn't matter what the file extentions are in linux but what is the convention for naming sed scripts? I have seen both .sh, .sed, .sd

Comment: Most people use `.sed` for a script containing only sed commands.

Comment: In fact, I have only very rarely seen .sed used as part of a filename for a sed script.  And I've been writing sed and awk scripts for going on 20 years.

Comment: I agree.  "Extensions" are an MS-DOSism that nobody needs anymore.

Comment: My sed scripts always end in `.pl`. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.sh` when the file contains shell commands; use `.sed` when it has only Sed commands and is loaded by `sed -f`.

E.g., the following would be called `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed 's/foo/bar/g'
```

While this would be `script.sed`:

```
s/foo/bar/g
```

Editors such as Vim will give you proper highlighting based on `.sh` and `.sed`.

Comment: Vim will give you proper highlighting by reading the first line of the file and determining the appropriate syntax from the name of the interpreter for the script.  No need to use DOS conventions at all.

Comment: Why would you name it `script.sed` instead of just `script`?  You don’t really name your shell scripts `script.sh` do you?

Comment: @tchrist: yes, I commonly use the `.sh` extension on scripts. I know I'm not required to, but it's a useful convention to follow.

Answer (score 2):

The convention is most likely *not* to put an "extension" on sed scripts.

In unix, a file is a file is a file.  There's no such thing as an extension.  Extensions are a dialect of FAT filesystems, and only used in unix by people who haven't fully migrated their thinking from the DOS/Windows world.

Name your files what they are.  Their content speaks for itself.

Comment: i know that I can name my files to exactly what I want but there is nice to know what's in the file without looking inside

Comment: Many Unix tools, including highlighting editors, will respond to file extensions.

Comment: @larsmans, they'll respond to file extensions because they follow [Postel's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle).  Just because you **can** do something doesn't mean you **should**.

Comment: They probably respond to filename extensions because these are a long-established tradition in the Unix world as well. If you look at early Unix source code, you'll find C sources files having `.c`, assembly files having `.s`, etc.